# Filter invoices by Customer ID PHP Devkit

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to filter invoices that I'm getting using QuickBook IPP and PHP devkit, but for some reason, quickbooks keeps sending back an empty result. My code is below:

```
$query = '<ContactIdSet><Id>340</Id></ContactIdSet>';
$invoices = $invoiceService->findAll($quickbooks->Context, $quickbooks->creds['qb_realm'], $query, 1, 999);
```

With this code, my request (minus Oauth info) is:

```
POST https://services.intuit.com/sb/invoice/v2/538361885 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Authorization: OAuth realm="",  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",  oauth_signature="",  oauth_nonce="GAmtH",  oauth_timestamp="1366692972", oauth_token="", oauth_consumer_key="",  oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Length: 298

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <StartPage>1</StartPage>
    <ChunkSize>999</ChunkSize>
        <ContactIdSet>
            <Id>340</Id>
        </ContactIdSet>
      </InvoiceQuery>
```

but even though there are invoices under that customer id, the response has no invoices:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2013 05:06:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
ContextInitTime: 9
Response-Id: cb8b6eaa-f810-4fad-9f69-3485f400680d
IdRestateTime: 4
HeaderQueryTime: 4
Content-Encoding: gzip
HeaderDAOTime: 4
Response-App-Time: 62
Response-Routing-Time: 67
Content-Length: 133
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><Invoices/></RestResponse>
```

Any ideas as to why quickbooks won't return the invoices that are associated with that customer?

Here is the XML response that shows the invoice exists when I use ->findAll()

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2013 17:44:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
LineQueryTime: 35
ContextInitTime: 94
Response-Id: 9b3d4e46-a6b5-4f90-81f4-3c42b0462330
AssemblingTime: 0
HeaderQueryTime: 91
Content-Encoding: gzip
HeaderDAOTime: 91
LineDAOTime: 35
Response-App-Time: 271
Response-Routing-Time: 276
Content-Length: 930
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><Invoices><Invoice><Id idDomain="NG">681891</Id><SyncToken>3</SyncToken><MetaData><CreateTime>2013-04-18T03:13:26.796Z</CreateTime><LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-23T03:49:05.800Z</LastUpdatedTime></MetaData><ExternalKey idDomain="QB">1189</ExternalKey><Synchronized>true</Synchronized><Header><DocNumber>WEB000126</DocNumber><TxnDate>2013-02-28T00:00:00Z</TxnDate><Status>Paid</Status><CustomerId idDomain="QB">340</CustomerId><CustomerName>Test, Ray &amp; Teryl</CustomerName><RemitToId idDomain="QB">340</RemitToId><RemitToName>Test, Ray &amp; Teryl</RemitToName><ShipDate>2013-02-28T00:00:00Z</ShipDate><SubTotalAmt>375</SubTotalAmt><TaxRate>0</TaxRate><TaxAmt>0</TaxAmt><TotalAmt>375</TotalAmt><ToBePrinted>true</ToBePrinted><ToBeEmailed>false</ToBeEmailed><ARAccountId idDomain="QB">64</ARAccountId><ARAccountName>Accounts Receivable</ARAccountName><SalesTermId idDomain="QB">8</SalesTermId><SalesTermName>Due on 1st</SalesTermName><DueDate>2013-03-01T00:00:00Z</DueDate><BillAddr><Id idDomain="QB">00000000000001cg</Id><Line1>Ray &amp; Teryl Test</Line1><Line2>3290 Test Test</Line2><City>Stone Mountain</City><CountrySubDivisionCode>GA</CountrySubDivisionCode><PostalCode>30087</PostalCode><Default>true</Default><Tag>Billing</Tag></BillAddr><ShipAddr><Id idDomain="QB">00000000000003rW</Id><Default>false</Default><Tag>Shipping</Tag></ShipAddr><BillEmail>Test@Test.com</BillEmail><Balance>0</Balance></Header><Line><Id idDomain="QB">1191</Id><Desc>Conservatory Registration Fee</Desc><Amount>125</Amount><Taxable>false</Taxable><ItemId idDomain="QB">14</ItemId><ItemName>Artios Conservatory</ItemName><ItemType>Service</ItemType><UnitPrice>125</UnitPrice><Qty>1</Qty><SalesTaxCodeId idDomain="QB">2</SalesTaxCodeId><SalesTaxCodeName>Non</SalesTaxCodeName></Line><Line><Id idDomain="QB">1192</Id><Desc>Preparatory Registration Fee</Desc><Amount>125</Amount><Taxable>false</Taxable><ItemId idDomain="QB">142</ItemId><ItemName>Elem Prep Reg (5/1-8/31)</ItemName><ItemType>Service</ItemType><UnitPrice>125</UnitPrice><Qty>1</Qty><SalesTaxCodeId idDomain="QB">2</SalesTaxCodeId><SalesTaxCodeName>Non</SalesTaxCodeName></Line><Line><Id idDomain="QB">1193</Id><Desc>Preparatory Registration Fee</Desc><Amount>125</Amount><Taxable>false</Taxable><ItemId idDomain="QB">142</ItemId><ItemName>Elem Prep Reg (5/1-8/31)</ItemName><ItemType>Service</ItemType><UnitPrice>125</UnitPrice><Qty>1</Qty><SalesTaxCodeId idDomain="QB">2</SalesTaxCodeId><SalesTaxCodeName>Non</SalesTaxCodeName></Line><Line><Id idDomain="QB">1194</Id><Desc>PayPal Convenience Fee</Desc></Line></Invoice></Invoices></RestResponse>
```

Comment: Can you post XML from ->findAll() *without the filter* that shows the invoice for that customer?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the XML that I get when I use findAll() without the filter. It shows that customer 340 has an invoice.

Comment: Wonderful... I'll file a support ticket with them. Can you think of any other way for me to get only the invoices I need without pulling down all the invoices and sorting them by customer myself?

Comment: The v3 data services (which should hit GA in September-ish) will have a much improved, more SQL-like query interface which should allow you to do some more advanced queries so you don't have to pull everything in. For now though, I think what most developers are doing are pulling the entire list (or pulling new/updated stuff with CDCAsOf) and caching it and handling the data in their app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an answer for the question, there is no support for that specific filter in v2 of the API.
You'll need to filter within your application

thanks
Jarred